# Rails params require permit, cast to right class

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my controller I have this method:

```
def project_params
   params.require(:project).permit(:name, :user_id)
end
```

And the create method. I check, if the logged in user @user, is the one for who the new project is made.

```
def create
   new_params = project_params
   return no_access if new_params[:user_id] != @user.id
   ...
end
```

And now my problem. I found out that when I POST the user_id as string via my API, the comparison doesn't make sense. As I compare String and Fixnum.
For example user_id = "10" and @user.id = 10.

One solution would be to use .to_i on the user_id parameter. However I have more cases than this example above.

So is there an easy way to automatically cast the params I get from project_params to the right class without changing the "require-permit" methods for every model in my project.

I didn't convert the values with .to_i in the first place as I thought rails gets the correct class from the respective database columns.

Comment: Project belongs to User? Why would you allow `:user_id` to be a param (a variable if you wish) then? If only @user.id is allowed, simply do: `@user.projects.create(project_params)`

Comment: Your code has a security issue. It's possible add project to any user if you have one account. I recommend for user authentification and authorization use devise gem or at least before_action hook.

Comment: I simplified the problem. There are multiple users who can create projects with different authorizations. The posted code is not the whole authorization process. But thank you for pointing out potential security issues.

Comment: The params hash is by definition a hash of strings (everything that comes from the client is type string). Using `to_i` is standard, but a DRYer way to fix it is to address the issue on the API side.

Comment: If you most compare the project_params[:user_id] to @user.id, is better to convert `@user.id.to_s` than project_params[:user_id]. You know @user.id is a number and responds to `.to_s`, but the parameter could be any value, not a string representation of an integer.

Comment: @Leito Yes you are right thanks for pointing this out